# Disable Swipe To Previous Month in DatePicker

Tags: android, datepicker, android-datepicker

Is their a way to disable `Datepicker` swiping for past month?

[image: sample]

I came across to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13661788/how-to-set-minimum-datepicker-date-to-current-date), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26033393/how-to-set-android-datepicker-dialog-max-date-to-current-date) . But it seems it will not disable the swiping / going back to previous month.

Reason : Setting a task in the present / future days.

Comment: Did my answer help you? If yes, consider accepting it

Answer (score 1):

You may create your own DatePickerDialog class. Then pass necessary date in milli currents when calling datePicker. `setMinDate()` method will disable previous days and swipe will also be disabled.

**DatePickerDialog class:**

```
public class myDatePickerDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    int mDay, mMonth, mYear;
    long current;

    // you also need to pass OnDateSetListener that is implemented in
    // activity which is calling this datePicker
    OnDateSetListener onSetDate;

    public myDatePickerDialogFragment(){
    }

    @Override
    public void setArguments(Bundle args) {
        super.setArguments(args);
        mDay = args.getInt("day");
        mMonth = args.getInt("month");
        mYear = args.getInt("year");
        current = args.getLong("minDate");
    }

    public void setOnDateSetListener(OnDateSetListener setDate){
        onSetDate = setDate;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), onSetDate, mYear, mMonth, mDay);

        // here you set minimum day. User cannot chose earlier dates.
        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(current);

        return datePickerDialog;
    }
}
```

Inside of Activity:

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt("day", mDay);
args.putInt("month", mMonth);
args.putInt("year", mYear);
args.putLong("minDate", yourCalendarObject.getTimeInMillis());

myDatePickerDialogFragment dialog = new myDatePickerDialogFragment();
dialog.setArguments(args);
dialog.setOnDateSetListener(datePickerListener);
dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "date");
```

OnDateSetListener:

```
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

        // do other work after date is set here

    }
};
```

Comment: @RoCk did you try my solution?